# Right behavior for variable-arity sum function

Tags: function, math, language-agnostic, sum, language-design

I'm defining a variable-arity `sum` function for a toy language.  It seems natural to me to allow it to be called without arguments and return `0`, but *real* languages (and their implementations) disagree among themselves.

Is there a use-case where returning zero would be less correct than throwing an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, the **[empty sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)** (the sum of no numbers) is defined to be zero.  To be mathematically correct, returning zero seems like the proper choice here.  Throwing an exception in this case would potentially complicate the use of your function, since you would have to be sure to guard each call with a try/catch in case you provide zero arguments somehow.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's one situation in which you might not want it to return zero: Suppose your language is dynamically typed and allows `+` to operate on non-numeric types (e.g., it might concatenate strings as in Python). Then an empty sum is ambiguous as to what kind of thing it's notionally summing: you might want the result to be 0 for numbers, "" for strings, [] for lists, etc.

If your language is like that, then you might choose to (1) return 0 anyway and accept that `sum(things)+other_thing` doesn't equal `sum(things together with other_thing)` except for numbers, (2) throw an exception, (3) return some special value that behaves like 0 when added to numbers, like "" when added to strings, etc., or (4) return (say) 0 anyway and say that 0+"" equals "" or something of the kind. Please do not do #4 if there is the slightest danger of the language ever being anything other than a toy.

Oh, and there's another related case: suppose your language is statically typed but has a powerful type inference mechanism. Then it might distinguish between summing no numbers and summing no strings, and return different things in the two cases. (But you'd need quite a sophisticated type system for make all that work, which I'd guess you wouldn't bother with for a toy language.)

Comment: In that case, the right answer would be to return the identity element for whatever binary addition operator that is.  It's not that you should throw an exception as much as should say "return identity."

Comment: The trouble is that your binary operator might not *have* a single identity element. If it adds numbers and concatenates strings, for instance, it won't have. (You might argue that something without an identity element shouldn't be called "+", nor its variadic version be called "sum", and you might be right, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: But those are two different operators - one is + defined over integers, and one is + defined over strings.  The operator is overloaded, but each individual operator has a definitive single identity element.

Comment: Are we talking here about the dynamic-typing case or the static-typing case? In the latter, I agree that it's better to think about such a `+` or `sum` as a single name overloaded with multiple functions (and I also agree, and explicitly said, that the Right Thing is to return the identity for the appropriate operator). For the dynamic-typing case, I don't think overloading is the right way to think about it.

Comment: In any case, `+` (or `sum`) will not operate on non-numeric values.

Comment: In that case I agree that returning 0 on empty arguments is the unique Right Thing.